# How to prove that $\widehat{m}(X) \overset{p}{\rightarrow} E\left ( y|\left \| x - X \right \| \leq \epsilon \right )$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose we have a random sample on the scalar random variable $y$ and the random k-vector $x$, and are interested in estimating the CEF (Cumulative Expectation Function) of $y$ given $x$, i.e., the function $m: \mathbb{R}^{k}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $$m(X) = E(y|x=X).$$

Suppose that $x$ has a continuous distribution and that $X$ is in its support. We pick some $\epsilon >0$ and let $$\widehat{m}(X) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_{i}I(\left \| x_{i}-X \right \|\leq \epsilon)}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} I(\left \| x_{i}-X \right \|\leq \epsilon)},$$
where $\left \| \cdot  \right \|$ is the usual Euclidean distance function.

We want to prove that $$\widehat{m}(X) \overset{p}{\rightarrow} E\left ( y|\left \| x - X \right \| \leq \epsilon \right ).$$

**My work:** We start from applying the **plim** operator on $\widehat{m}(X)$. So $$\text{plim  }\widehat{m}(X)$$
$$= \text {plim   }  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_{i}I(\left \| x_{i}-X \right \|\leq \epsilon)}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} I(\left \| x_{i}-X \right \|\leq \epsilon)}$$ 
$$= \text {plim   }  \frac{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_{i}I(\left \| x_{i}-X \right \|\leq \epsilon)}{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} I(\left \| x_{i}-X \right \|\leq \epsilon)}$$ 
$$= \frac{\text {plim   }   \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_{i}I(\left \| x_{i}-X \right \|\leq \epsilon)}{\text {plim   }   \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} I(\left \| x_{i}-X \right \|\leq \epsilon)}, \text{ (by Slutsky's Theorem)}$$ 
$$ = \frac{E\left ( y I(\left \| x_{i}-X \right \|\leq \epsilon) \right )}{E\left ( I(\left \| x-X \right \| \leq \epsilon) \right )} \text{ (by Khinchine's Law of Large Numbers)}$$
$$ = \frac{E\left ( y I(\left \| x_{i}-X \right \|\leq \epsilon) \right )}{Pr\left ( I(\left \| x-X \right \| \leq \epsilon) \right )} \text{ (by property of the indicator function I)}.$$

Any ideas on how I can finish the proof from here? Also, why do we need $\epsilon > 0$ for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done, just note that 
$$
\frac{E(YI(||x-X|| \le \epsilon)}{E(I(||x-X|| \le \epsilon))} = \frac{E(Y_{I(||x-X|| \le \epsilon)})}{P(||x-X|| \le \epsilon)} = E(Y|  \|x-X\| \le \epsilon).
$$